# Strange differential eqn

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've a strange question here which I don't really understand. I've been asked to solve for $f(x)$:

$f '(x) + af(x) = bg(x) + ch(x) +dl(x)$

And I don't understand how I'm supposed to get that in terms of $f$ without having more information. $f,g,h$ and $l$ are functions. $a,b,c,d$ are constants. The variable $x$ is real and greater than zero. Is this some sort of error in the question?

Comment: You cannot assume that $f$ is a polynomial, since in general it will not. What would you have done with $f'(x)+af(x)=k(x)$, i.e. with just one function in the right-hand side? Also, please use [mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) while writing your questions.

Comment: It is a first order linear differential equation, so one can write the solution in terms of $x \mapsto e^{-ax}$ and the convolution of same with the input  $x \mapsto b g(x)+ch(x)+d l(x)$.

Comment: Edited appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$q(x)=bg(x)+ch(x)+dl(x)...(1)$$
So the EDO you wish to solve is
$$f'(x)+af(x)=q(x)...(2)$$
An integrant factor of ($2$) is $\mu(x)=\exp\left[\int a\,dx\right]=e^{ax}$, then
multiplying ($2$) by $\mu(x)$ yields
\begin{align}e^{ax}f'(x)+ae^{ax}f(x)&=e^{ax}q(x)\\
\frac{d}{dx}\left[e^{ax}f(x)\right]&=e^{ax}q(x)...(3)\\
e^{ax}f(x)&=\int e^{ax}q(x)dx+C\qquad\text{By integrating eq. (3)}\\
f(x)&=e^{-ax}\int e^{ax}q(x)dx+Ce^{-ax}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

First let $b=c=d=0$ and solve

$$f'(x)+af(x)=0,$$

i.e.
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\left(\ln(f(x))\right)'=-a$$
hence the solution

$$f(x)=Ce^{-ax}.$$

Now let $b=1$ and solve

$$f'(x)+af(x)=g(x).$$

You try the "constant variation" method, i.e. let $C$ be a function of $x$.

$$f(x)=c(x)e^{-ax}$$ then
$$f'(x)=c'(x)e^{-ax}-ac(x)e^{-ax},$$ and

$$f'(x)+af(x)=c'(x)e^{-ax}=g(x),$$or
$$c'(x)=e^{ax}g(x).$$

By integration,

$$c(x)=\int e^{ax}g(x)dx+C,$$and
$$f(x)=e^{-ax}\left(\int e^{ax}g(x)dx+C\right).$$

Now you can replace $g(x)$ by the full RHS.